# Fixing id field in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

While troubleshooting another problem, I added `self.primary_key = id` to my model. This broke ActiveRecord's management of the id field. Is there any way to revert back? Code was removed and app was restarted. The problem is the schema changed. An explicit id field was added and

`create_table "sales_orders", force: true do |t|` was changed to

`create_table "sales_orders", id: false, force: true do |t|`

So the main issue now is I've lost auto-incrementing.

Comment: please explain what is broken, usually removing the code you added should fix the problem.

Comment: Revert that change, delete all corrupted records and you should be fine

Comment: I added some information to the question

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there must be another solution, but what I ended up doing was dropping the table and recreating it combining the previous migrations that affected it.